# Grails: Connecting jconsole to local process on specified port

Tags: java, grails, jmx, jconsole

I am trying to connect jconsole to a specified port for a local process. I can connect to the local process using the PID but not using the remote option.
I am using ubuntu 14.04 and JDK 1.7
This is what I am doing to run my app.

```
grails  \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx \
-Dserver.port=8090 \
run-app
```

**hostname -i** also gives me **xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx**

Comment: What version of Grails?  If 2.3.x or later and the app is running in forked mode then those `-D` options will affect the JVM that is running Grails, not the one that is running the target application.

Comment: I am using Grails **2.4.0**. I am running the grails app and jconsole both on localhost. And I don't have two different JVMs so both using the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the below code to resources.groovy resolved the issue for me.

```
String serverURL = grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL
URL url = new URL(serverURL)
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "${url.host}")
rmiRegistry(org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean) {
    port = 9999
    alwaysCreate: true
}


serverConnector(org.springframework.jmx.support.ConnectorServerFactoryBean) { bean ->
    bean.dependsOn = ['rmiRegistry']
    objectName = "connector:name=rmi"
    serviceUrl = "service:jmx:rmi://${url.host}/jndi/rmi://${url.host}:9999/jmxrmi"
    environment = ['java.rmi.server.hostname'                 : "${url.host}",
                   'jmx.remote.x.password.file'               : "${grailsApplication.parentContext.getResource('/WEB-INF/jmx/jmxremote.password').file.absolutePath}",
                   'jmx.remote.x.access.file'                 : "${grailsApplication.parentContext.getResource('/WEB-INF/jmx/jmxremote.access').file.absolutePath}",
                   'com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate': true,
                   'com.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only'  : false,
                   'com.sun.management.jmxremote'             : true]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Grails 2.3 and later uses ["forked mode"](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#forkedMode) by default, where the JVM running `run-app` spawns a separate process to run the target application.  Therefore, rather than passing the `-D` options to `grails` you should configure them in `BuildConfig.groovy`.  Find the `grails.project.fork` option and add `jvmArgs`:

```
grails.project.fork = [
  run:[...., jvmArgs:['-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true',
    '-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999', 
   // etc.
  ]]
]
```

Using the `-D` options on the command line as you are currently doing will set up the JMX connector in the *grails* process, not in your application.

Comment: Still no luck. Then how jconsole is able to connect using local process and pid. And I am able to see all these properties on **jconsole->MBeans->java.lang->Runtime->Attributes->System Properties**. And instead of grails 2.4.0, I tried my approach on grails 2.0.4 also and there also I am not able to connect using remote process option.